# Merge content not processing flow files further

Tags: merge, apache-nifi

I have a nifi flow which deals with ingestion of large data on a daily basis, as I will be getting data from server I need to validate the source count from flow file,each of my flow files would consists of some 100 records.Here i'm working on a sample flow by using some flowfiles using the below flow.The problem i'm facing here(my actual problem for server data as well) is that while I try to merege the data few records are merging fine but after that the flow files are not moving further.these are my merge content settings. I need help sorting out this issue in any possible approach.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think, it's because of the backpressure `original` connection (you see the red color)

Comment: Hi Tony, I tried increasing the back pressure but I see no change, any other way without using merge content.